# Remove a hash change in url while click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, url, hash

It is possible to remove hash element on Accordion when Tab element is clicked?
I use Accordion in Visual Composer in Wordpress.

I have some code:

```
<ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#ID-element-1">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#ID-element-2">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#ID-element-3">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#ID-element-4">Tab 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and

```
<div class="vc_tta-panel" id="ID-element-1>SOME TEXT 1</div>
<div class="vc_tta-panel" id="ID-element-2>SOME TEXT 2</div>
<div class="vc_tta-panel" id="ID-element-3>SOME TEXT 3</div>
<div class="vc_tta-panel" id="ID-element-4>SOME TEXT 4</div>
```

The problem which I mention is in accordion - when I click in Tabs - url gets hash and ID - I don't want hash, only ID. I just need a small 'solution' how I can remove a hash change in url while click event.

Comment: `$('.vc_tta-tab a').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault() })` will stop the URL changing, the rest is down to whatever other you need to do, but this will stop the browser moving to the hash position, you'll need to code that in.

Comment: The hash is still in the URL. Do you have an idea how to code this?

Comment: I tried this code: $(".vc_tta-tab a[href*='#']").each(function(){
      var t = $(this);
      var url = t.attr('href').replace('#', '');
      t.attr('href', url);
  }) and hash was removed from URL, but nothing happend when I clicked on Tab

Comment: There is something missing in what you are telling us. See https://jsfiddle.net/k8knb1eu/

Comment: @Marek you can check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825117/3821823

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure JavaScript Code

```
var linkElement = document.querySelectorAll('.bullet-toc ul li a');
            linkElement.forEach(function(item){
                item.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var hyperLink = this.getAttribute('href');
                    var redirectTo = hyperLink.replace('#', '');
                    document.getElementById(redirectTo).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
                })
            })
```

Hope this could be helpful ~ RDaksh

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this:

**Updated: 29/06/2017 17:40**

If you want to urls change without hash you can use like below. What's the important point?. We use [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) now.

```
$(".vc_tta-tab > a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  let getID = $(this).attr('href')
  $("div").hide();
  $(getID).show();
  history.pushState(null, null, getID.replace('#', ''))

})
```

This is a so basic example for you, so could be bad practice. You can implement to use with jQuery.

**jQuery Way:**

```js
$(".vc_tta-tab > a").on("click", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  let getID = $(this).attr('href')
  $("div").hide();
  $(getID).show();
})
```

```css
.vc_tta-panel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#ID-element-1">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#ID-element-2">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#ID-element-3">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#ID-element-4">Tab 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="vc_tta-panel" id="ID-element-1">SOME TEXT 1</div>
<div class="vc_tta-panel" id="ID-element-2">SOME TEXT 2</div>
<div class="vc_tta-panel" id="ID-element-3">SOME TEXT 3</div>
<div class="vc_tta-panel" id="ID-element-4">SOME TEXT 4</div>
```

**VanillaJS Way:**

```js
//select all tab elements
const clicked = document.querySelectorAll(".vc_tta-tab > a")

// iterate all tab elements
clicked.forEach((k,i) => {
 
  // handle clicked tab element
 clicked[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
    
    //get clicked link's href attributeç
  let getID = clicked[i].getAttribute('href');
  
    //hide all divs
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".vc_tta-panel")).forEach(function(value){
   value.style.display = "none";
  });
    
    // show clicked div.
  document.querySelector(getID).style.display = "block";
 });
})
```

```css
.vc_tta-panel {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#ID-element-1">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#ID-element-2">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#ID-element-3">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#ID-element-4">Tab 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="vc_tta-panel" id="ID-element-1">SOME TEXT 1</div>
<div class="vc_tta-panel" id="ID-element-2">SOME TEXT 2</div>
<div class="vc_tta-panel" id="ID-element-3">SOME TEXT 3</div>
<div class="vc_tta-panel" id="ID-element-4">SOME TEXT 4</div>
```

Comment: Don't work, when I click tab - everything on window is hiding. I think you don't understand me. I want to remove "#" element in URL when I click in Tab. after this "#" is ID div element with text.

Comment: Okey, I'm trying to understand you.

What about this example? http://statistician-sink-84650.bitballoon.com/

Comment: Not exactly. I want this situation - when I click e.g. Tab.1 - URL will change to http://statistician-sink-84650.bitballoon.com/ID-element-1, so URL = domain+page+ID-element, without "#"

Comment: @Marek

Okey, I prepared an example for you. http://warrior-candidates-16134.bitballoon.com/

If you want to something like that you should use history API. For example:

`history.pushState(null, null, getID.replace('#', ''))`

And you should know, pushState is not store real URL. So, when you refresh page, maybe you can get 404 error.

Comment: Ok, cool, i meant it. But is there any possibility that after entering e.g. in external service on this link it will open normally with correct content (not 404 error)?

Comment: Could you answer me?

Comment: @Marek I have no idea. I explained you what I'm know.

Comment: I think it is not possible. Thank you, you were helpful.